# View fields from the same database column

Tags: 7, views, entities, ubercart

So, I have serialized data within the uc_orders table. This data has several parameters of interest each of which I want to create a unique field from.

Each one of these $data values work on their own. Obviously I am rewriting the value on the second declaration. How can I reference the same data location twice so that both of the fields can be used and I can explode all of my serialized data into separate fields?

```
  function uc_order_views_data() {
    $data['uc_orders']['data'] = array(
      'group' => t('Order') . ':data',
      'title' => t('Arrival Date'),
      'help' => t('Arrival date choosen by customer during checkout.'),
      'field' => array(
      'handler' =>'uc_order_handler_field_arrive_date',
        'click sortable' => TRUE,
      ),
      'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      ),
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
      ),
    );

    $data['uc_orders']['data'] = array(
      'group' => t('Order') . ':data',
      'title' => t('Ship Date'),
      'help' => t('The date to ship the order by.'),
      'field' => array(
      'handler' =>'uc_order_handler_field_ship_date',
        'click sortable' => TRUE,
      ),
      'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      ),
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

```
  $data['uc_orders']['data2'] = array(
    'group' => t('Order') . ':data',
    'title' => t('Arrival Date'),
    'real field' => 'data',
    'help' => t('Arrival date choosen by customer during checkout.'),
    'field' => array(
    'handler' =>'uc_order_handler_field_arrive_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
     ),
     'sort' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
     ),
     'filter' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
     ),
  );

  $data['uc_orders']['data'] = array(
    'group' => t('Order') . ':data',
    'title' => t('Ship Date'),
    'help' => t('The date to ship the order.'),
    'field' => array(
    'handler' =>'uc_order_handler_field_ship_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
     ),
     'sort' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
     ),
     'filter' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
     ),
  );
```

The solution is to add `'real field' => 'field name',` and change the $data id.